# How do I join a channel if it has already been created in hyper ledger fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, channel, peer

I am using hyper ledger fabric V2.5 with go language.

I created "my channel" on test-network and I have two organizations each has one peer. How can I join my channel after bring up the network?

Do I need to run ./network.sh createChannel command every time to join channel?

I'm new to Hyper ledger fabric. Looking for guidance. Thanks in advance.